# How do black hole properties change with added mass?

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, black-holes, angular-momentum, mass

How do the spin, lifespan, radiation, gravity, and relativistic effects (time dilation in relation to proximity) change as you start from minimal mass to more massive black holes (not limited to the mass realistically possible, but limited by how far our equations can go before breaking (since I want to avoid hypotheticals (though feel free to point out any leading theories if you want)))?

Comment: You may enjoy exploring the [Hawking radiation calculator](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator). Unfortunately, it's only for black holes without spin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equations of GR do not "break" at some value of a black hole mass.

- Spin: A black hole of any mass can have spin bounded by: $J^2 /M^2 + Q^2 \leq M^2$
- Lifetime: A larger black hole would have larger lifetime. The mass is lost by Hawking radiation. More massive black holes (of the same angular momentum and charge) have lower temperatures.
- Gravity/ Relativity: Im not sure what you mean. More massive black holes have stronger gravitaional fields around them.

Comment: By the relativistic effects. I was curious about the time dilation in terms of proximity. Furthermore, do (or is it assumed that) these relations hold true at extremely high orders of magnitude such as a googol?

Comment: Time dialation has no fundamental difference in different masses. This is true as long as GR is true.

Comment: What do you mean by GR is true? Wouldn't an increase in mass mean an increase in gravity which would mean different time dilation under GR?

Comment: yep. no fundamental difference, just a stronger effect.